# How to set a label's title based on it's inner HTML?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

I have an html form field with lots of checkboxes.

How to set a label's title attbibased on it's inner HTML? I need to do this for all titles.

For example, I need to transform

```
<div id=field>
  <label class='option'>Ski</label>
  <label class='option'>Hockey</label>
  <label class='option'>Baseball</label>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id=field>
  <label title='Ski' class='option'>Ski</label>
  <label title='Hockey' class='option'>Hockey</label>
  <label title='Baseball' class='option'>Baseball</label>
</div>
```

I tried the following jQuery code:

```
$('#field label.option').attr('title',$(this).html());
```

but it gives me tons of garbage.

So how to get the value inside each matching label?

This is jQuery 1.4.4.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you post the html you have?

Comment: why you are not using div with id's

Comment: @atom217 - I do. The actual HTML was much more complex, this is just a simplified version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#field label.option').attr('title',function(){ return $(this).text() });
```

Answer (score 2):

`title` attributes should contain text only, so you'd be better to user [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('#field label.option').prop('title', function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

If you absolutely *have* to set the `title` to the inner HTML, use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('#field label.option').prop('title', function() { return $(this).html(); });
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5L3MF/)

Comment: Yes, the title contains text.

Comment: I use jquery 1.4.4. and the prop method was only added on version 1.6

Comment: OK, just replace `prop()` for `attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
$('.option').each(function(i,lbl)
   {
       $(lbl).attr('title',$(this).html());
   }
);
```